# ASP.NET Core MVC customizing site variables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC (with EF) site and I want administrators to modify some variables via admin panel. For example contact e-mail, counter section visibility, navigation menu visibility etc.

And most of the parameters are in `_Layout.cshtml`.

May I learn the best practice how to manage this issue.

For example: I have a one row table that named GeneralSettings and it has some columns (IsLoginEnable, IsPrivacyVisible etc.) and want to read these columns in _Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
@if (true) //for example I want to write here "if (Model.ToList()[0].IsLoginEnable)" instead of this
{
    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
}
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    </li>
    @if (true) //if (Model.ToList()[0].IsPrivacyVisible)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </li>

    }
</ul>
```

I've added comments near the if conditions that I actually want to do.

Comment: Can you show us some code and describe your question in detail？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated Answer

- Seed your `GeneralSettings` on the application first start.
- The admins can modify it from the UI using a regular form.
- When needed, get it from the server's memory via the `IMemoryCache` service. If it's not present in the memory fetch it from the database and cache it.
- When a modification in the `GeneralSettings` occures, purge it from memory using the `IMemoryCache` service.

The below code is just an example and may need to be modified to work in your application.

Turn your `GeneralSettings` into a service:

```cs
public Interface IGeneralSettingsService
{
   Task<GeneralSettings> GetSettingsAsync();
}
```

```cs
public class GeneralSettingsRepo : IGeneralSettingsService
{
  //Inject Context...
  //Inject IMemoryCache...

  public async Task<GeneralSettings> GetSettingsAsync() 
  {
    if (!memoryCache.TryGetValue("GeneralSettings", out GeneralSettings GS))
    {   
        GS = await context.GeneralSettings.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    
        _ = memoryCache.Set<GeneralSettings>("GeneralSettings", GS, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(cachehours),
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(cachehours)
        });
    }
    return GS;
  }
}
```

In your admin controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateGlobalSettings(SettingsVm vm)
{
   //Update properties...
   memoryCache.Remove("GeneralSettings"); //Purge old settings from cache
}
```

And finally in your `Layout.cshtml` inject the settings service:

```
@inject IGeneralSettingsService GeneralSettingsService
@{
   var settings = await GeneralSettingsService.GetSettingsAsync();
}
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
@if (settings.IsLoginEnabled)
{
    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
}
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    </li>
    @if (settings.IsPrivacyVisible)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Don't forget to register the service in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: thank you very much HMZ, and which controller is this get action belongs to? and how can i call it on application start? could you create a tiny app please?